# How to expand nodes once tree is loaded?

Tags: angular, typescript, settimeout

Hi I am developing web application in Angular 5. I am loading trees in my web page.
I am using data from API to bind it to tree nodes. This tree is dynamic.
As soon as tree loaded, I want to expand it.

```
addrule(row, ruleValue) {
        this.roleservice.getRulesbyUserRoleId(row.userroleid).subscribe(result => this.getRulebyUserRoleIdSuccess(result,row), error => this.getRulebyUserRoleIdError(error));
        this.treecreate.treeModel.expandAll();
    }
```

In the above code, after tree is loaded, I am trying to expand tree. This is throwing error cannot read property treemodel of undefined. So I put one button on my web page and  tried to call function on button click. When the user clicks on expandall button below fucntion will be called.

```
expnadall(){
      this.treecreate.treeModel.expandAll();
}
```

This code works and my tree expands. Can someone help me to figure out the issue? Any help would be appreciated. Thanks

Comment: Have you tried to invoke `expandall` in `ngAfterViewInit`. Can you show a minimal working example? Where do you load the tree?

Comment: I dint try yet. I have created stackbliz but i could not make it work https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-5-tutorial-jpkajy?embed=1&file=app/app.component.ts

Comment: I tried ngAfterViewInit and it dint work

Comment: I think in the example the component ´tree-root´  is missing?

Answer (score 0):

You said you are "*using data from API to bind it to tree nodes*". For this reason, I assume that the data used to build the tree is actually fetched by the `this.roleservice.getRulesbyUserRoleId(row.userroleid)` call. After **the instruction that performs the call**, you try to expand all the nodes in the tree with the `expandAll()` method.

There is a little "problem" with that. Looking at your code the `getRulesbyUserRoleId(...)` call is an asynchronous call that returns an Observable.

I took the liberty to reformat your code so that the issue will be more evident.

```
addrule(row, ruleValue) {
    this.roleservice.getRulesbyUserRoleId(row.userroleid)
        .subscribe(
            result => this.getRulebyUserRoleIdSuccess(result,row), 
            error => this.getRulebyUserRoleIdError(error)
        );

    this.treecreate.treeModel.expandAll();
}
```

Let's see what happens now:

- somehow `addrule(row, ruleValue)` gets called
- `roleservice.getRulesbyUserRoleId(row.userroleid)` gets called, and two handlers are attached to the just created Observable. They will get executed at a later time, when the Observable is ready to emit some value (.. or some error).
- **`this.treecreate.treeModel.expandAll()` is called**
  ...
  ...
  ...
- at some unknown time, one of the two subscribed handler on the Observable gets called.

So, what does this mean? Again, I assume that the `this.getRulebyUserRoleIdSuccess(result,row)` method is responsible for the creation of the tree - using the data returned by the service call. If that is the case, this also means that the tree probably isn't available until said method executes - **do you by any chance set the `this.treecreate` variable inside the  `getRulebyUserRoleIdSuccess` method??**.

As we said before, there is no guarantee that the `this.getRulebyUserRoleIdSuccess(result,row)` call will get executed before the `this.treecreate.treeModel.expandAll()` one (quite the opposite, actually) and by consequence there is no guarantee that you won't try to expand the tree before creating it in the first place.
This is also coherent with the other behavior you are experiencing: the button that invokes the same `expandAll()` method on the tree works correctly - *because by the time you press the button, the tree has already been built*.

If that is the case and I was able to deduce the full picture from the quick summary in your question, fixing the issue should be very simple: just move the `expandAll()` call so that it gets executed after the tree is created. Something like this may work:

```
addrule(row, ruleValue) {
    this.roleservice.getRulesbyUserRoleId(row.userroleid)
        .subscribe(
            result => {
                this.getRulebyUserRoleIdSuccess(result,row);
                this.treecreate.treeModel.expandAll();
            },
            error => this.getRulebyUserRoleIdError(error)
        );
}
```

As a final warning: again, assuming that this in indeed the issue you are facing, it is unclear if this is simply the result of a typo or copy/paste error (or maybe you are working on someone else code) or if you aren't yet very used to javascript Promises / Observable handling. If the later, I suggest you try to have a quick watch at some online course / tutorial: the concepts behind promises aren't really very hard to grasp, but can easily create a lot of confusion if not completely grasped.